# Use Where in LinQ Contains when there is lot of data coming using Entity framework

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use Contains in a variable. My code as follows:-

```
var lista = Service.Loads.ToList().Where(
   x => facility.Contains(x.Facility)).ToList();
```

My code doesn't move forward since `Service.Loads.ToList()` contains hundreds of thousands of records. How should I modify my code?

Comment: What is the type of Service.Loads ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the first `.ToList()`?

Comment: Is there a reason that You are calling `ToList()` on `Loads`? The `ToList()` at the end should be enough. Everytime you call `ToList()` it will create a brand new list in memory which is very time consuming.

Comment: It gives me error

Comment: You should be more descriptive...

Comment: Is `Service.Loads` already in memory? Or is it in the database (E.g. Entity Framework DataSet)?

Comment: @rahulaggarwal: What is the error?  What is `facility`?  What is `x.Facility`?

Comment: Service.Loads it is from database, I am getting the table using edmx

Comment: Remove  `ToList` from here `Loads.ToList()`.

Comment: If I remove .ToList() from Loads.ToList() then I get error "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.OData.Client.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not convert constant System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] expression to string."

Comment: why downvote the question guys?

Comment: @JerryGoyal Yeah, not sure why this is downvoted. It's a legitimate question on how to construct queries when using EF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to load all the entities. You do this by calling the `.ToList()` eagerly:

```
Service.Loads.ToList()
```

You could remove the `.ToList()` and only do it at the end:

```
var lista = Service.Loads.Where(x => facility.Contains(x.Facility)).ToList();
```

Except that won't work, because EF will try to transform your expression to a SQL statement and it can't do that because `facility` is an in-memory object.
(I see you already tried that and it indeed throws a `NotSupportedException`)

You'd have to find a different way to construct the where-clause without using an in-memory object. For example:

```
    var facilityIds = facility.Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
    var lista = Service.Loads.Where(x => facilityIds.Contains(x.Facility.Id)).ToList();
```

That is, if `facility` has an ID-property, otherwise you'd have to find a different property to match on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try following code

```
var lista = Service.Loads.Where(x => facility.Contains(x.Facility)).ToList();
```

This is something [LateBinding](http://blog.falafel.com/understanding-ienumerable-iqueryable-c/) ,Which is used internally .

Comment: already tried giving me error "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.OData.Client.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Could not convert constant System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] expression to string."

Comment: your code might be ToList before Where condition .Try to remove it .as Mentioned by me.